# Playwright: How to ignore query params in waitForUrl() and toHaveUrl()?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Is it possible to expect page toHaveURL and ignore query params in Playwright?

I'm trying to check:

```
await expect(page).toHaveURL('/clients/new');
```

But the current url is e.g.:

```
https://server.com/clients/new?sort=name&direction=desc
```

If I use a regular expression, I have to substitute a server name that is different locally, in docker, in ci, and on prod. It's ok for now, but I don't like it :)

I expect toHaveURL to be true if the url has query params.

Comment: What's the issue with `await expect(page).toHaveURL(/\/clients\/new/);`? If you have different URLs to test, can you share what those are?